# Dominated convergence on $e^{-n^2 t} t^{s/2-1}$

Tags: inequality, integration, asymptotics

> I am trying to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to show that
>   $$\sum_{n\ge 1} \int_0^1 e^{-n^2 t} t^{s/2-1}dt= \int_0^1 \sum_{n\ge 1}e^{-n^2 t} t^{s/2-1}dt$$ as soon as $s>1$.

I've noted that
$$\int_0^1 t^a t^{s/2-1}dt$$
converges if and only if $s>-2a$. So we would need to prove that
$$\sum_{n\ge
> 1}e^{-n^2 t}\ll t^{-1/2}.$$
Of course,
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}e^{-n^2 t}\le\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2t}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{1}{t},$$
but that's not good enough... I could get a $t^{1/2}$, but this would give me a $\sum_{n\ge 1} 1/n=\infty$. How can I get such a thing ?

Comment: Isn't everything non-negative?

Comment: You can do this using the monotone convergence theorem

Comment: @Amr Whoups, I was telling myself that I couldn't apply the monotone convergence theorem because $e^{-n^2t}$ is decreasing, but the sequence is the sum. Nontheless, I'm still interested about knowing how to bound the sum efficiently to use dominated convergence.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-n^2 t}$ is easy to compare with
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-n^2 t}\,dn = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{t}} $$
and in particular
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-n^2 t}< \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-n^2 t}\,dn $$
since $f(n)=e^{-n^2 t}$ is a decreasing function. For further accuracy, you may use the [Euler-MacLaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).